# AddComment causes application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, comments

I keep getting an error message attempting to use the `.AddComment` method, I've tried various expressions, but am having no luck. Currently my code reads

```
Cells(cellRow, CellCol).Select
With Selection
    .Interior.color = vbRed
    .AddComment
        With .Comment
         .Text Text:helpfulComment
         .Shape.ScaleWidth 5.6, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
         .Shape.ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        End with
End With
```

Error message reads,

> Run-time Error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error

which breaks on the `.Addcomment` line

Comment: Does the cell already have a comment? That is usually the cause of this error

Answer (score 3):

Its' because you can't add a comment to a range that already has a comment

so you have two ways

**1st way** - check for a comment to be already there

```
Sub main()
    With Cells(cellRow, CellCol) 'reference wanted range
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then .AddComment ' Add a comment if not already there
        With .Comment ' reference the comment object of the referenced range
            .Text "Text: helpfulComment"
            .Shape.ScaleWidth 5.6, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .Shape.ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**2nd way** - clear the Comment anyway (doesn't throw any error if range has no Comment) and add it right afterwards

```
Sub main()
    With Cells(cellRow, CellCol) 'reference wanted range
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .ClearComments ' Clear referenced range comments, if any
        With .AddComment ' add and reference a new comment object of the referenced range
            .Text "Text: helpfulComment"
            .Shape.ScaleWidth 5.6, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .Shape.ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```